# How to check if DTMF tones generated are correct(using an Android phone)?

Tags: android, dtmf

I have a circuit which produces DTMF signals corresponding to 1,2,3 etc... I can see the waveforms on the CRO as well. I am also using a speaker which produces these DTMF tones corresponding to each key . Is there a way i can use these tones to dial any number using my android phone?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to record the tones and software decode them, then turn around an use an android API to place a call to the detected number.

Audible tones in the environment aren't going to dial a mobile phone they way they would a pots landline.  There might still be post-answer services you can activate by injecting tones into the audio input, but mobile codecs such as GSM can distort tones quite a bit on top of whatever environmental noise is present, so that may not work very well.